# Do errors in Javascript (console errors like reference errors) affect SEO?

Tags: seo, javascript, error, debug

Suppose I have an error in my console on a couple of pages, like the following:

```
(index):239 Uncaught ReferenceError: incom is not defined
    at (index):239
    at dispatch (jquery.min.js?ver=1.8.3:2)
    at u (jquery.min.js?ver=1.8.3:2)
```

Does this, in any way, affect SEO or can I safely ignore it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any **error** or improper implementation of Javascript(in any form) is affecting the **crawlability** or preventing crawlers from **fetching content**, it can affect SEO in a drastic way.

If this error affects any of the processes, the crawlers may not favour your website over others.

Even after fixing errors, there should be some things to be kept in mind while implementing Javascript.

Do not use Javascript’s onclick events as a replacement for internal linking. Instead, use regular anchor tags within the HTML or the DOM.

Unblock Javascript. When Javascript is blocked, search engines won't receive your site’s full experience. This means that the search engine could not see what the end-users are seeing on your site, and can even lead to search engines interpreting it as cloaking.

Use [Fetch as Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch?pli=1) to see how are the pages read by robots.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear answer. Appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Anuvesh's answer is correct.  It will only hurt SEO directly if the error prevents the bot from seeing the content in the page.

It could also hurt SEO indirectly if it makes the site less usable for visitors.  Google may notice if users are turning away from your site.

However, if the problem is invisible to users that don't open the developer tools, it should have no affect on SEO.  Google has long said that they don't prefer sites based on how "correct" that site is.  For example [Google doesn't rank sites better if they pass HTML validation](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-validation-seo-23784.html).

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer!

Comment: @Stephen, Suppose that the solution to fix a javascript error would simply be to put an if condition around the statement to prevent it from running when conditions are such that it would fail. Or in other words, I didn't actually want it to run anyway under such circumstances, so no content is being missed. Would errors like this have any effect on SEO?

Comment: I'm not sure about that @bvernon maybe you should ask a whole new question and spell out exactly what you're trying to do a little bit more.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks, it was just a curiosity when I read this as I'm thinking about the hundreds of times I've seen js errors in websites I'm working on, but no one ever fixes them because fixing them b/c nothing is really "broken" in regard to the fact that fixing them wouldn't actually change the behavior of the website in any way... it would only get rid of the js error from the console. Well, I fix them b/c they annoy me, but no one else does, lol.

Comment: If the only negative consequence if console log entries, it shouldn't hurt SEO of usability in any way.